# Where are the elements in a python list stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Take this example object:

```
class myObj:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
a = myObj()
```

I can use `vars(a)` and I'll get `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` or `dir(a)` to get a list of the attributes plus all the functions in a. I can see everything that is stored within `a`.

However, with a list its a different story. `var([])` throws an error and `dir([1, 2, 3])` only lists the functions that are implemented in list. Where does `__getitem__` get the items in the list from?

Comment: You are correct in that `var([])` throws **an** error, but not for the reason you think: `NameError: name 'var' is not defined`. What you probably meant: `vars([])` throws `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`. Also, never say you got **an** error without saying which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your typical Python distribution (known as CPython), built-in types like lists are implemented in C, not Python. After all, it can't be Python all the way down! This means that the inner workings are hidden, and no attributes will reveal them.

On a similar note, you will find that `inspect.getsource([].__getitem__)` doesn't work.